# Javascript click event stop anchor href link

Tags: javascript, anchor

When include js click event the anchor tag href doest work 
The HTML:

```html
<li id="serviciosbtn"><a href="#servicios">SERVICIOS</a></li>
```

The JS

```
var servicios = document.getElementById("serviciosbtn");

servicios.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        nav.classList.add("hide-mobile");
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

That actually apply the class but the a href is now not working

Comment: e.preventDefault(); is probably the reason you are not seeing the behavior of hyperlink working

Comment: Works fine for me https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/60h98vkg/1/. @ullfindsmit why? It's not bound to the anchor.

Comment: Your #servicios is a local page link not external and it scrolled up in jsfiddle in your original post you have your <a inside the <li

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**e.preventDefault(); is the only reason**
[Read the official documenation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

> Try removing the e.preventDefault(); 
>   it will behave normally

Answer (score 0):

@ullfindsmit, yes, when i delete e.preventDefault() it works